# fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/myrepo/frontend/' After denying git credentials

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-code

I was about to push something to my git remote on github. VSCode usually asks me in a popup to do something like allow access to my git. I normally put in my computer password and proceed. But this time I pressed **Deny**.

Right after, when I tried again to push to the remote I started getting:

```
Missing or invalid credentials.
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED /var/folders/q6/npwl_7xj4wg91lg06f8pnnfh0000gn/T/vscode-git-320456bc0a.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/var/folders/q6/npwl_7xj4wg91lg06f8pnnfh0000gn/T/vscode-git-320456bc0a.sock'
}
Missing or invalid credentials.
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED /var/folders/q6/npwl_7xj4wg91lg06f8pnnfh0000gn/T/vscode-git-320456bc0a.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/var/folders/q6/npwl_7xj4wg91lg06f8pnnfh0000gn/T/vscode-git-320456bc0a.sock'
}
remote: No anonymous write access.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/myrepo/frontend/'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quitting and restarting VSC fixed the issue. It prompted vscode to authorize through github in the browser.